# How to pass pdf files to php

Tags: iphone, ipad, file-upload

I have a form with a `file upload field`. It works fine, but sometimes I can't open submitted `.pdf` files. I checked it out and saw that when getting $_FILES in PHP sometimes `.pdf` file size is 0kb. How to avoid this and get all files correctly.